# Exportar a excel data frames en R

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio, r-dplyr

Tengo un data frame que necesito exportarlo a excel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el excel necesito que las columnas sean los años, la primera fila el código y los valores de precipitaciones mensuales estén para cada año y código. El excel debería tener una hoja para cada mes, Por ejemplo, la hoja del mes de Abril debería ser similar a esto

```
`código  2000   2001   2002 ....  2019
 87345   116.3
 87347   103.6
 ....
 87467
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)
```

Primero pasar a formato Wide los años con la funcion pivot_wider

```
   df_1 = df %>% 
      pivot_wider(names_from = anio,values_from = precip.mensual)
```

Luego separar el df en una lista con los df mensuales con la función split

```
df_1 %>% split(df_1$mes) %>% write.xlsx("df_por_mes.xlsx")
```

La funcion write.xlsx entiende que cada elemento de la lista es una pestaña